# Graduate numerical analysis books

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation

I am a first year graduate student, and I am looking for a good numerical analysis book to self-study. Ideally, I am looking for a book that introduces the basics of floating point arithmetic, interpolation, solutions to non-linear equations, and numerical methods in ODE's and PDE's. More importantly, I would like a book that has good exercises as well. I will most likely be taking a course on numerical PDE next term so I am looking for a book that would help me brush up on numerical analysis.

Comment: So you would like to learn mathematical physics. Then numerical analysis first authored by Richard L. Burden would be a good option. For ODEs and PDEs, I guess you would like to learn properties of operators (laplace operator, for instance) and structures of solutions spaces of different equations. I guess having a good understanding of linear algebra would be necessary. Books specifically on PDEs depend on your need. If you would like to be an engineer, then any book containing Laplace equation and Helmholtz equation would be a good start. If you are a mathematician, then I have no idea.

Comment: Richard Hamming's Numerical Methods book is quite good.

Comment: [Stoer and Bulirsch](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Numerical-Analysis-Applied-Mathematics/dp/144193006X) is very good.